# Automatically don't save buffers before compiling

Tags: compile-mode

I often have buffers from unrelated projects open. Before compiling I use projectile-save-project-buffers to save all relevant buffers. If other buffers happen to contain unsaved modifications, however, I will still be prompted about them, before I can compile.

Now there is compilation-ask-about-save:

```
compilation-ask-about-save is a variable defined in ‘compile.el’.
Its value is t

Documentation:
Non-nil means M-x compile asks which buffers to save before compiling.
Otherwise, it saves all modified buffers without asking.

You can customize this variable.

[back]
```

The problem is, that I don't want to save those unrelated buffers. Is there another variable that I'm missing? Can I configure emacs in a way so that it just compiles the current saved state without further prompts?

Comment: There is a `compilation-save-buffers-predicate`.

Comment: Since Emacs 28 you can customize `save-some-buffers-default-predicate`
with the new value `save-some-buffers-root`.  This will restrict
the prompts to buffers under the current project (or in a subdir
of the dir where the caller is invoked, if no project is found).

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me is to add:

```
;; Don't save anything before compiling
(setq compilation-save-buffers-predicate 'ignore)
```

Thanks to xuchunyang for pointing it out!